# Split DNS (bind9), match-clients any doesn't work?

Tags: debian, networking, dns, bind

I've been fighting with this for the last few days. A few of my entries have external and internal IP's. My internal network is 10.0.0.0/8.

When I `nslookup pc1.clase.net` internally it responds with a 10.0.0.0 address but if I `nslookup  pc1.clase.net` externally it still gives me a 10.0.0.0  address.

I'm on Debian Wheezy.

#### named.conf

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
view "internal" {
  match-clients { 10.0.0.0/8;};
  zone "clase.net"{
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/internals/db.forward.net";
    allow-transfer { 10.0.0.11/8; }
  };
};
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";

zone "10.in-addr.arpa" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/internals/db.reverse.net";
  allow-transfer { 10.0.0.11/8;
  };
};
};

view "external" {
  match-clients { any; };
  zone "clase.net" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/externals/db.forward.net";
    allow-transfer { 10.0.0.11/18;
    };
  };
};
```

#### internal/db.foward.net

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns.clase.net. root.clase.net. (
                     2 ; Serial
                         604800 ; Refresh
                          86400 ; Retry
                        2419200 ; Expire
                         604800); Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  ns.clase.net.
ns  IN  A   10.0.0.10
pc1 IN  A   10.0.0.12
```

#### external/db.forward.net

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns.clase.net. root.clase.net. (
                     2 ; Serial
                         604800 ; Refresh
                          86400 ; Retry
                        2419200 ; Expire
                         604800); Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  ns
    IN  A   150.210.0.1
ns  IN  A   150.210.0.1
pc1 IN  A   150.210.0.22
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally found out how to do it.

Requires the TSIG keys to differentiate the 2 zones.

[Example](https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00296/0/My-slave-server-for-both-an-internal-and-an-external-view-has-both-views-transferred-from-the-same-master-view-how-to-resolve-.html)

Comment: please provide a (full) example in the answer, rather than linking to remote sites (that will happily change URLs,... and no one will be any the wiser). also, if this solves your problem, please *accept* the answer (even if it's your own)

Comment: The example you provide is from a master/slave conf; I noticed indeed your configuration in your OP seems correct, does it means you are were dealing with your configuration not working in a SLAVE DNS node? People could not guess. Cheers

Comment: Yep.  That's the way to go, is to use the key/IP-pair ACL since Bind9 9.3.

https://bind9-users.isc.narkive.com/XujqCth1/match-clients-and-tsig-keys

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your issue but in looking at your config file it looks like you have some typos in it.

#### Example

This block looks like it has too many closing braces (`};`).

```
zone "10.in-addr.arpa" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/internals/db.reverse.net";
  allow-transfer { 10.0.0.11/8;
  };
};
};
```

Should be this, no?

```
zone "10.in-addr.arpa" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/internals/db.reverse.net";
  allow-transfer { 10.0.0.11/8; }
};
```

#### Cleaned up version of your `named.conf` file.

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
view "internal" {
  match-clients { 10.0.0.10/24;};
  zone "clase.net" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/internals/db.forward.net";
    allow-transfer { 10.0.0.11/8; };
  };
};

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";

zone "10.in-addr.arpa" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/internals/db.reverse.net";
  allow-transfer { 10.0.0.11/8; };
};

view "external" {
  match-clients { any; };
  zone "clase.net" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/externals/db.forward.net";
    allow-transfer { 10.0.0.11/18; };
  };
};
```

#### wrong client network?

These lines look incorrect to me:

```
view "internal" {
  match-clients { 10.0.0.0/8;};
  zone "clase.net"{
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/internals/db.forward.net";
    allow-transfer { 10.0.0.11/8; }
  };
};
```

Should be this, no?

```
view "internal" {
  match-clients { 10.0.0.0/8;};
  zone "clase.net"{
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/internals/db.forward.net";
    allow-transfer { 10.0.0.0/8; }
  };
};
```

#### References

- [BIND 9 Configure Views To Partition External and Internal DNS Information](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bind9-named-configure-views/)

Comment: Thanks for answering, Afraid that removing the named.conf.default-zones from the internal view gives me a fatal error:Default-zones when using view statements, all zones must be in views And ive noticed a silly error of mine. the clients for internal  view is 10.0.0.0/8

Comment: @ultorian - that was gonna be my next question, the IP's were 10.0.0.11/8 which I thought was wrong. Did that resolve the issue then?

Comment: nope no luck, it was a typo in the code inserted here, not the real code :( I'm actually starting to doubt my "external" network..

Comment: @ultorian - can you walk me through how the external hosts are querying the DNS server?

Comment: @ultorian - also you might want to compare your setup to this one, see if you've missed anything? http://www.howtoforge.com/two_in_one_dns_bind9_views

Comment: Master server and slave server are both virtual machines, both with bridged adapters to the host, creating the 10.0.0.0 network, the host is connected to a real router by the WAN port, with its IP 10.0.0.16 and a laptop connected to that router by a lan port with 192.168.1.2 . A ping from the 10 network to 10.0.0.16 results in an error. So i might of found my problem

Comment: which i don't understand since the laptop has no trouble contacting with the VM's

Comment: And aye, howtoforge was page i initially followed, ill revise it in case ive missed something.

Comment: Cant find anything.. 4am, im going to bed, thanks for your help slm,  good night

Comment: Your reverse zone is outside any view declarations, as is the `include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones` clause. When you're using views, those need to be inside a view declaration - if you want them to be the same in both views, you'll need to list them once in each view.

Answer (score 0):

**-Here take a look!!!**

**named.conf**

```
// If you are just adding zones, please do that in /etc/bind/named.conf.local

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
include "/etc/bind/t-sig.key";
```

**named.conf.options**

```
acl internals {
                127.0.0.0/8;
                10.0.0.0/8;
              };

options {

    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    allow-recursion     { internals; };
    allow-query-cache   { internals; };
    allow-query         { internals; };

    dnssec-enable     yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;

     forwarders {

        // -Google - JUST FOR SAMPLE!!!
        8.8.4.4;
        8.8.8.8;

    };

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

**named.conf.local**

```
include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

acl internals {
    127.0.0.0/8;
};

    zone "localhost" { 
        type master; 
        file "/etc/bind/db.local";
     };

};
```

**named.conf.default-zones**

```
// prime the server with knowledge of the root servers

    zone "." {
        type hint;
        file "/etc/bind/db.root";
    };

// be authoritative for the localhost forward and reverse zones, and for
// broadcast zones as per RFC 1912

    zone "sample.net" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.sample.net";
        allow-query     { internals; };
        allow-transfer  { key t-sig.key; };  
    };

    zone "localhost" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.local";
        allow-query { 127.0.0.0/8; };
        allow-transfer  { key t-sig.key; };
    };

    zone "127.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/127.in-addr.arpa";
        allow-query { 127.0.0.0/8; };
        allow-transfer  { key t-sig.key; };
    };

    zone "10.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/0.0.10.in-addr.arpa";
        allow-query { internals; };
        allow-transfer  { key t-sig.key; };
    };

    zone "0.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/0.in-addr.arpa";
        allow-query { internals; };
    };

    zone "255.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/255.in-addr.arpa";
        allow-query { internals; };
    };
```